# Need a help to resolve Azure Functions issue

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am working on Azure Function in which i am trying to use **FunctionContext**.
Also i am using **.net 6.0 framework and VS2022** for development.
Same FunctionContext is used in another project which has **.net 5.0 framework**

`public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log, **FunctionContext functionContext**)`

But when i am trying to execute function i am getting below error:

> [2022-11-22T12:57:35.388Z] Function 'TimeTriggerTest' failed indexing
> and will be disabled. [2022-11-22T12:57:35.389Z] No job functions
> found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using
> binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make
> sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in
> your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(),
> builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
> [2022-11-22T12:57:35.427Z] The 'TimeTriggerTest' function is in error:
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'TimeTriggerTest'.
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'functionContext'
> to type FunctionContext. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by
> the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage,
> ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration
> method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.
> builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(),
> builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

I have included **Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker** pakages too in the project.
As per error, i got to know that its asking to add something in startup.cs file.
But suggestion which are suggested are not part of builder object (**interface IFunctionsHostBuilder**)

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Its hard to tell from your question, but did you forget the `[Function]` attribute by any chance?

Comment: No. I have added  [FunctionName("TimeTriggerTest")] attribute. Also if i remove FunctionContext i am able to execute function without error

Comment: If you are using `FunctionContext` then I believe you are using an isolated process? If so, the `ILogger` should come from the `FunctionContext` [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#execution-context). You are leaving out a lot of information from your question though that makes it really difficult to help. Ideally you would provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: can you provide the packages you're using in your cs proj?

Comment: I think i got the problem. While creating Azure project need to create project as .Net 6.0 Isolated (Long Term Support). I used .Net 6.0 (Long term Support) while creating the project. I have just verifed by creating demo project with Isloated and its working fine, without error. Also its not required to add Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker pakages too. I will work and will update you. Thanks all for your quick response.